# how to send an additional parameter for Telerik MVC [JQuery] event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, telerik-mvc

I'm new to jQuery right now I'm using Telerik asp.net MVC control along with Razor view engine. Here is a code snippet from my view.

```
    Html.Telerik().ComboBox().Name("cmb")                
    .AutoFill(true)
    .DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax().Select("_loadData", "MyController").Cache(false))
    .ClientEvents(ce => ce.OnLoad("cmbLoaded"))

    function cmbLoaded(e) {            
        var ComboBox = $("#cmb").data("tComboBox");
        //do stuff here
    }
```

Ok this what I'm trying to do I want to send extra parameter to the telerik Combobox event say cmbLoaded event handler. how can i do that.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It's been awhile but a ran into a similar situation.  The string you pass as a parameter to the OnLoad event is a Javascript function reference, so you can pass something like:

```
.ClientEvents(ce => ce.OnLoad("function(e) { cmbLoaded.call(this,e," + Model.Id + "); }"))
```

Then your Javascript function signature would change to:

```
function cmbLoaded(e, id)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to submit extra parameter when your combo is fetching the data from the server?
Then you can send it with the help of the [OnDataBinding](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-combobox-client-api-and-events.html#OnDataBinding) event.
For example:

```
function onComboBoxDataBinding(e){
 e.data={extraParameter:"Cool"};
}
```

Comment: I want to send extra parameter on cmbLoaded

.ClientEvents(ce => ce.OnLoad("cmbLoaded"))

how should i pass it here.

Comment: onLoad does not perform any request to the server ... it is triggered when the combo is initialized on the client.

Comment: I don't even want to send anything to the server side I never said it. I'm only focusing on the client side in this question. I'm talking about sending extra parameter to the attached event handler for onLoad event of telerik control. its all client side script. 
please do read the question if you can't answer then don't waste others time.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by defining some variables in a code block, and then use them in your javascript event handler. Here is an example:

```
@{
   string myPar1 = "some text";
   int myPar2 = 10;
}

<script type="text/javascript">

function cmbLoaded(e, '@myPar1' @myPar2) {            
        var ComboBox = $("#cmb").data("tComboBox");
        //do stuff here
    }

</sciprt>
```

Comment: seems like a workaround but just curious to know if there is any way to send some additional properties of the control without declaring variable locally

Comment: Inside the event handler you can get any data you someway attached to a control. Having defined @(Html.Telerik().ComboBox().Name("name").HtmlAttribute(new { data_mydata="test"})). Inside handler: var cmp = $(this).data('tComboBox'); var myData = cmp.$wrapper.data('mydata');